# How to correctly use the inject method in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm still a ruby newbie and I'm trying to learn how exactly to use the `inject` method.

By using the `inject` method, I'm trying to return an array of letters and their appearance in a given string like so:

```
def sorting(str)
  str.split("").uniq.map { |letter|
    [letter, str.split("").inject(0) { |sum, char| sum + 1 if letter == char }]
  }
end

p sorting("aaabdbbcccaaabcacba")
```

The desire result should be:

```
[["a", 8], ["b", 5], ["d", 1], ["c", 5]]
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting an error: `undefined method '+' for nil:NilClass`.

**What am I doing wrong and how can I solve it using `inject` and its sum advantages?**

Comment: @ArupRakshit You're right. I update it. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

using [`Enumerable#group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) seems more appropriate:

```
>> "aaabdbbcccaaabcacba".chars.group_by { |x| x }.map { |key, a| [key, a.size] }
=> [["a", 8], ["b", 5], ["d", 1], ["c", 5]]
```

### Problem of the given code:

The block passed to inject does not care about non-matching character.

Replace `sum + 1 if letter == char` with `letter == char ? sum + 1 : sum`:

```
def sorting(str)
    str.split("").uniq.map { |letter|
        [letter, str.split("").inject(0) { |sum, char| letter == char ? sum + 1 : sum }]
    }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to go :

```
s = "aaabdbbcccaaabcacba"
s.chars.uniq.map{|c|[c,s.count(c)]}
# => [["a", 8], ["b", 5], ["d", 1], ["c", 5]]
```

Comment: This takes O(m*n) time. (m = number of unique items, n = number of all items).

Comment: @falsetru Looks very clean...so I wrote it.. :)